# What is the correct syntax for api_version in app.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

I was previously using "api_version: 1" but when I update to "api_version: 2" I get the error "api_version '2' is not supported by the 'python27' runtime." I also tried 1.1 with the same error message. I'm sure it is something simple, but haven't found it yet.

Comment: That is not a syntax error. It tells you that the Python version you are running only supports API version 1. The documentation says: *"At this time, App Engine has one version of the python27 runtime environment: 1"* https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Required_elements

Comment: Ah, you're right. The right thing to update was version, not api_version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to update "version: 1" to "version: 2", not "api_version: 1" to "api_version: 2". And, just for the record, "version: 1.1" did not work.